# Samba authentication via LDAP

Tags: debian, ldap

Could you please tell me how did you enable samba authentication via LDAP ?
I saw your post but could not find any steps :(

Thanks in advance.

Maniyeri

Answer (score 1):

There are "ldap" options group in smb.conf. For example:

```
...
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://ldapserver.address/
ldap admin dn = cn=samba,ou=DSA,dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=ORG
ldap suffix = dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=ORG
ldap user suffix = ou=Users
... etc.
```

Then you have to use 'smbpasswd -w ldapppassword' to store password, which samba will use to connect to LDAP database. Google *'smbldap-tools'* for more explanations.

Comment: Hey, you're not Tim.